# Metaprogramming sample from Wikipedia

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Trying to understand sample from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming)

```
template <int length>
Vector<length>& Vector<length>::operator+=(const Vector<length>& rhs) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        value[i] += rhs.value[i];
    return *this;
}

template <>
Vector<2>& Vector<2>::operator+=(const Vector<2>& rhs) 
{
    value[0] += rhs.value[0];
    value[1] += rhs.value[1];
    return *this;
}
```

Firsttly I can't compile it at all. I got error syntax error : `missing ';' before '<'`

And second question is how to use it?
As far as I understand template name `Vector` is not the same like `std::vector`.

Comment: this is just part of a `Vector` class. it cannot be compiled alone. and you'll also need calling code to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just (a small) part of a Vector class, showing a concept for teaching purposes.

It cannot be compiled alone. You'll have to write the rest of the class.

Then you'll have to write calling code which instantiates the template and calls the operators to test it. Then debug it (or add trace messages) to show that the right overload is resolved.

Note also that it says "the following code may be produced". You don't actually need the second code. It just shows what an optimizer compiler can do with your code.

Answer (score -3):

Try defining the class like:

```
template <int length>
class Vector
{
    Vector<length>& operator+=(const Vector<length>& rhs);
    Vector<2>& operator+=(const Vector<2>& rhs);
};
```

I would recommend going for an online C++ tutorial

Comment: My first answer, which is a good and working answer, I don't understand the vote downs, if I was wrong I would understand.

Comment: (Not my vote) The `<2>` bit doesn't do what you think it should do, nor is it related to the Wikipedia example.

Comment: Right, but 1) it is correct 2) it matches the code.

Comment: No, you define `template <int len> Vector<2>& Vector<len>::operator+=(const Vector<2>& rhs)` - note the inconsistent template arguments. In particular, `return *this` won't work for `len!=2`.